# Calculation of e performance issue

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, mathematics

Can you give me some idea how to optimize the `switch` statements, maybe a `for` or `do while` loop? Which is faster, `switch` or `for`/`while` loop?

```
public class CalculateTheValueOfE {

    static long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    static int numberOfThread = 4;
    private static int precision = 0;
    private static int threadCount = 0;
    private static String defaultFile = null;

    static BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE;

    public static BigDecimal factorial(int x) {
        BigDecimal prod = new BigDecimal("1");
        for (int i = x; i > 1; i--) {
            prod = prod.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
        }
        return prod;
    }

    public static Runnable getRunner(final int from, final int to) {
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BigDecimal e = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
                for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
                    e = e.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3 * 3 * i * i + 1).divide(factorial(3 * i), new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)));
                }
                addResult(e);
            }
        };
        return runner;
    }

    public static synchronized void addResult(BigDecimal e) {
        result = result.add(e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //Thread tr[] = new Thread[threadCount];
       // Runnable r[] = new Runnable[numberOfThread];

        File file = new File("result.txt");
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fis);
        System.setOut(out);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(i + " " + args[i]);

        }
        threadCount = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        precision = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);
        defaultFile = args[5];
        System.out.println("Number of threads: " + threadCount + " precision: " + precision + " default file to save the result: " + defaultFile);
        //String numberOfThreads = args[1];
        //String precision = args[3];
        //String defaultFile = args[5];
        int calculation = precision / threadCount;

        /* for (int i = 1; i<= precision; i+=calculation){
         Runnable r = getRunner(i, calculation + 1);
         Thread t = new Thread(r);
         t.start();
         t.join();
         i=250;
         }*/
        switch (threadCount) {
            case 1:
                Runnable r1 = getRunner(1, precision);
                Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t1.start();
                t1.join();
                break;

            case 2:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 2 + 1);
                Runnable r2 = getRunner(precision / 2 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                break;

            case 3:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 3 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 3 + 1, 2 * precision / 3 + 1);
                Runnable r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 3 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                break;

            case 4:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 4 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 4 + 1, 2 * precision / 4 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 4 + 1, 3 * precision / 4 + 1);
                Runnable r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 4 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                Thread t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                break;

            case 5:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 5 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 5 + 1, 2 * precision / 5 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 5 + 1, 3 * precision / 5 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 5 + 1, 4 * precision / 5 + 1);
                Runnable r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 5 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                Thread t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                break;

            case 6:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 6 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 6 + 1, 2 * precision / 6 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 6 + 1, 3 * precision / 6 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 6 + 1, 4 * precision / 6 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 6 + 1, 5 * precision / 6 + 1);
                Runnable r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 6 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                Thread t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                break;

            case 7:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 7 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 7 + 1, 2 * precision / 7 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 7 + 1, 3 * precision / 7 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 7 + 1, 4 * precision / 7 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 7 + 1, 5 * precision / 7 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 7 + 1, 6 * precision / 7 + 1);
                Runnable r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 7 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                Thread t7 = new Thread(r7);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                break;

            case 8:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 8 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 8 + 1, 2 * precision / 8 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 8 + 1, 3 * precision / 8 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 8 + 1, 4 * precision / 8 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 8 + 1, 5 * precision / 8 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 8 + 1, 6 * precision / 8 + 1);
                r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 8 + 1, 7 * precision / 8 + 1);
                Runnable r8 = getRunner(7 * precision / 8 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t7 = new Thread(r7);
                Thread t8 = new Thread(r8);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t8.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                t8.join();
                break;

            case 12:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 12 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 12 + 1, 2 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 12 + 1, 3 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 12 + 1, 4 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 12 + 1, 5 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 12 + 1, 6 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 12 + 1, 7 * precision / 12 + 1);
                r8 = getRunner(7 * precision / 12 + 1, 8 * precision / 12 + 1);
                Runnable r9 = getRunner(8 * precision / 12 + 1, 9 * precision / 12 + 1);
                Runnable r10 = getRunner(9 * precision / 12 + 1, 10 * precision / 12 + 1);
                Runnable r11 = getRunner(10 * precision / 12 + 1, 11 * precision / 12 + 1);
                Runnable r12 = getRunner(11 * precision / 12 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t7 = new Thread(r7);
                t8 = new Thread(r8);
                Thread t9 = new Thread(r9);
                Thread t10 = new Thread(r10);
                Thread t11 = new Thread(r11);
                Thread t12 = new Thread(r12);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t8.start();
                t9.start();
                t10.start();
                t11.start();
                t12.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                t8.join();
                t9.join();
                t10.join();
                t11.join();
                t12.join();
                break;

            case 16:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 16 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 16 + 1, 2 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 16 + 1, 3 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 16 + 1, 4 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 16 + 1, 5 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 16 + 1, 6 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 16 + 1, 7 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r8 = getRunner(7 * precision / 16 + 1, 8 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r9 = getRunner(8 * precision / 16 + 1, 9 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r10 = getRunner(9 * precision / 16 + 1, 10 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r11 = getRunner(10 * precision / 16 + 1, 11 * precision / 16 + 1);
                r12 = getRunner(11 * precision / 16 + 1, 12 * precision / 16 + 1);
                Runnable r13 = getRunner(12 * precision / 16 + 1, 13 * precision / 16 + 1);
                Runnable r14 = getRunner(13 * precision / 16 + 1, 14 * precision / 16 + 1);
                Runnable r15 = getRunner(14 * precision / 16 + 1, 15 * precision / 16 + 1);
                Runnable r16 = getRunner(15 * precision / 16 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t7 = new Thread(r7);
                t8 = new Thread(r8);
                t9 = new Thread(r9);
                t10 = new Thread(r10);
                t11 = new Thread(r11);
                t12 = new Thread(r12);
                Thread t13 = new Thread(r13);
                Thread t14 = new Thread(r14);
                Thread t15 = new Thread(r15);
                Thread t16 = new Thread(r16);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t8.start();
                t9.start();
                t10.start();
                t11.start();
                t12.start();
                t13.start();
                t14.start();
                t15.start();
                t16.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                t8.join();
                t9.join();
                t10.join();
                t11.join();
                t12.join();
                t13.join();
                t14.join();
                t15.join();
                t16.join();
                break;

            case 20:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 20 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 20 + 1, 2 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 20 + 1, 3 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 20 + 1, 4 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 20 + 1, 5 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 20 + 1, 6 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 20 + 1, 7 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r8 = getRunner(7 * precision / 20 + 1, 8 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r9 = getRunner(8 * precision / 20 + 1, 9 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r10 = getRunner(9 * precision / 20 + 1, 10 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r11 = getRunner(10 * precision / 20 + 1, 11 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r12 = getRunner(11 * precision / 20 + 1, 12 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r13 = getRunner(12 * precision / 20 + 1, 13 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r14 = getRunner(13 * precision / 20 + 1, 14 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r15 = getRunner(14 * precision / 20 + 1, 15 * precision / 20 + 1);
                r16 = getRunner(15 * precision / 20 + 1, 16 * precision / 20 + 1);
                Runnable r17 = getRunner(16 * precision / 20 + 1, 17 * precision / 20 + 1);
                Runnable r18 = getRunner(17 * precision / 20 + 1, 18 * precision / 20 + 1);
                Runnable r19 = getRunner(18 * precision / 20 + 1, 19 * precision / 20 + 1);
                Runnable r20 = getRunner(19 * precision / 20 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t7 = new Thread(r7);
                t8 = new Thread(r8);
                t9 = new Thread(r9);
                t10 = new Thread(r10);
                t11 = new Thread(r11);
                t12 = new Thread(r12);
                t13 = new Thread(r13);
                t14 = new Thread(r14);
                t15 = new Thread(r15);
                t16 = new Thread(r16);
                Thread t17 = new Thread(r17);
                Thread t18 = new Thread(r18);
                Thread t19 = new Thread(r19);
                Thread t20 = new Thread(r20);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t8.start();
                t9.start();
                t10.start();
                t11.start();
                t12.start();
                t13.start();
                t14.start();
                t15.start();
                t16.start();
                t17.start();
                t18.start();
                t19.start();
                t20.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                t8.join();
                t9.join();
                t10.join();
                t11.join();
                t12.join();
                t13.join();
                t14.join();
                t15.join();
                t16.join();
                t17.join();
                t18.join();
                t19.join();
                t20.join();
                break;

            case 24:
                r1 = getRunner(1, precision / 24 + 1);
                r2 = getRunner(precision / 24 + 1, 2 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r3 = getRunner(2 * precision / 24 + 1, 3 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r4 = getRunner(3 * precision / 24 + 1, 4 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r5 = getRunner(4 * precision / 24 + 1, 5 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r6 = getRunner(5 * precision / 24 + 1, 6 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r7 = getRunner(6 * precision / 24 + 1, 7 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r8 = getRunner(7 * precision / 24 + 1, 8 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r9 = getRunner(8 * precision / 24 + 1, 9 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r10 = getRunner(9 * precision / 24 + 1, 10 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r11 = getRunner(10 * precision / 24 + 1, 11 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r12 = getRunner(11 * precision / 24 + 1, 12 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r13 = getRunner(12 * precision / 24 + 1, 13 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r14 = getRunner(13 * precision / 24 + 1, 14 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r15 = getRunner(14 * precision / 24 + 1, 15 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r16 = getRunner(15 * precision / 24 + 1, 16 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r17 = getRunner(16 * precision / 24 + 1, 17 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r18 = getRunner(17 * precision / 24 + 1, 18 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r19 = getRunner(18 * precision / 24 + 1, 19 * precision / 24 + 1);
                r20 = getRunner(19 * precision / 24 + 1, 20 * precision / 24 + 1);
                Runnable r21 = getRunner(20 * precision / 24 + 1, 21 * precision / 24 + 1);
                Runnable r22 = getRunner(21 * precision / 24 + 1, 22 * precision / 24 + 1);
                Runnable r23 = getRunner(22 * precision / 24 + 1, 23 * precision / 24 + 1);
                Runnable r24 = getRunner(23 * precision / 24 + 1, precision);
                t1 = new Thread(r1);
                t2 = new Thread(r2);
                t3 = new Thread(r3);
                t4 = new Thread(r4);
                t5 = new Thread(r5);
                t6 = new Thread(r6);
                t7 = new Thread(r7);
                t8 = new Thread(r8);
                t9 = new Thread(r9);
                t10 = new Thread(r10);
                t11 = new Thread(r11);
                t12 = new Thread(r12);
                t13 = new Thread(r13);
                t14 = new Thread(r14);
                t15 = new Thread(r15);
                t16 = new Thread(r16);
                t17 = new Thread(r17);
                t18 = new Thread(r18);
                t19 = new Thread(r19);
                t20 = new Thread(r20);
                Thread t21 = new Thread(r21);
                Thread t22 = new Thread(r22);
                Thread t23 = new Thread(r23);
                Thread t24 = new Thread(r24);
                t1.start();
                t2.start();
                t3.start();
                t4.start();
                t5.start();
                t6.start();
                t7.start();
                t8.start();
                t9.start();
                t10.start();
                t11.start();
                t12.start();
                t13.start();
                t14.start();
                t15.start();
                t16.start();
                t17.start();
                t18.start();
                t19.start();
                t20.start();
                t21.start();
                t22.start();
                t23.start();
                t24.start();
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
                t3.join();
                t4.join();
                t5.join();
                t6.join();
                t7.join();
                t8.join();
                t9.join();
                t10.join();
                t11.join();
                t12.join();
                t13.join();
                t14.join();
                t15.join();
                t16.join();
                t17.join();
                t18.join();
                t19.join();
                t20.join();
                t21.join();
                t22.join();
                t23.join();
                t24.join();
                break;
        }
       /* if (threadCount == 1) {
            Runnable r1 = getRunner(1, precision);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
            t1.start();
            t1.join();
        }*/


        /* Runnable r1 = getRunner(1, calculation + 1);
         Runnable r2 = getRunner(calculation + 1, 2 * calculation + 1);
         Runnable r3 = getRunner(2 * calculation + 1, 3 * calculation + 1);
         Runnable r4 = getRunner(3 * calculation + 1, 4 * calculation);
         Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
         t1.start();
         Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
         t2.start();
         Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
         t3.start();
         Thread t4 = new Thread(r4);
         t4.start();
         t1.join();
         t2.join();
         t3.join();
         t4.join();*/
        System.out.println("e = " + result);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = stop - start1;
        System.out.println("Time: " + diff + " ms");
        System.out.println("Count of Threads: " + threadCount);
        System.out.println("Precision: " + precision);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Which is faster, switch or for/while loop?

The speed difference for you here regarding a switch or a for/while loop is **nothing** compared to the rest of your code. You should really not be worried about that here.

<sub>That being said, I believe a switch is technically faster, but as I said. You shouldn't worry about that there!</sub>

You should be worried about maintainability, flexibility and readability. In which case a for-loop is substantively better.

#### Unexpected Results without Error Messages

Imagine the user currently inputting "10" as the number of threads. Then what happens? E becomes 1. No error message. This can be very confusing for a user (Based on a true story). **Your current `switch` approach does not support that option.**

To fix this, either a) Add a `default` statement to your `switch`, stating that the chosen number of threads is not a valid option. b) Add support for it by **using a for-loop instead!**

#### Get rid of the `static` habit!

Instead of getting used to `static`, create an instance of your class and pass the required variables to it's constructor (such as `precision` and `threadCount`) and then use a non-static method to make the computations.

I think that the reason you're using static is that it's the "easiest/fastest" approach. But I'm warning you: It might come around and haunt you. I recommend avoiding over-using static.

By using the non-static approach and passing arguments to the constructor, you can mark several fields as **final** which is considered a good practice when possible.

#### Unused variables

```
static int numberOfThread = 4;
int calculation = precision / threadCount;
```

These variables does not seem to be used. Remove them.

#### Other comments

- Use `BigDecimal.ONE` instead of `new BigDecimal("1")`
- Instead of computing time with `System.currentTimeMillis();` use `System.nanoTime();`
- Create and return on same line. Instead of `Runnable runner = new Runnable...` you can `return new Runnable...`
- You have some commented code without explaining why it is commented. Remove that code next time before posting it for review to reduce confusion.

Once again though, most importantly:

## Don't use `switch` here, use `for`!

([See answer by @VoiceOfUnreason](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/53825/31562))

Answer (score 6):

You should write out your code so that what you are trying to do is clear.  In this case, there are a number of distinct steps

1. Create a bunch of Runnable
2. Start them all
3. Wait until they have all finished
4. Report the result

For part #1 -- you commented out `Runnable[]` but that was close to the right idea.  I would instead recommend a List

```
List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
    int low = 1 + (i * precision / threadCount);
    int high = 1 + ((i+1) * precision / threadCount);

    tasks.add( getRunner(low,high) ) ;
}
```

For part #2 -- create an instance of an `ExecutorService`, and submit all of the tasks to it.  There are a number of different [ExecutorService implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), with different strategies to determine how they are run.  Your implementation suggests that you want everything on a thread of its own, so perhaps

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
for(Runnable task : tasks) {
    executor.submit(task);
}
```

For part #3, you can signal to the executor service that all tasks have been submitted, and then wait until they all finish.

```
// let the service know that all tasks are submitted
executor.shutdown();

executor.awaitTermination(...);
```

You're likely to have contention on the `addResult()` method, because all of the worker threads need to block waiting for each other to do that part of the calculation.  You might get a small improvement by writing the intermediate results to a thread safe queue, and adding another task that reads the events out of that queue to do the addition.

There are data structures, like a ring buffer, that can handle the thread contention more easily.  Take a look at [Disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor), which is a library specifically designed for many threads writing data to one single consuming thread.

Comment: Is it normal for precision = 10000 and 1 thread that the program never gets build?

Answer (score 5):

Your I/O is eccentric.

`args[0]`, `args[2]`, and `args[4]` are ignored.  `args[5]` is also required, but the program never does anything with it.

Code in `main()` should be kept to a minimum — just enough to process the arguments.  There should be another method, such as `public static BigDecimal e(int precision, int threads)` that does the "real" work, so that your class can be called by other code in the future.

Hard-coding `result.txt` is user-unfriendly and limits the reusability of your code.  I suggest printing your diagnostics to `System.err` and the output to `System.out`.  Let the user redirect `System.out` to a file using the shell, if desired.  Your program shouldn't have to worry about such things.

The thread-spawning code really ought to be generalized.  There should be an array of `Thread`s rather than a large number of `Thread` variables.

Calculating `factorial()` from scratch is wasted work.  You should be able to compute factorials based on factorials computed in previous terms.

Consider [other algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18445/77144) for calculating *e*.

Comment: can you give me some idea how to rewrite factorial(),because i should use this kind of calculation .Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with `MathContext`: you are creating a new object at each addition operation which could really lower your performance.

Here is another replacement for your switch statement using Java 8's [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). I don't really recommend using this at the moment since it is very new and few Java programmers know about Streams.  I also used some "functional" programming concepts from Java 8, so some part of the code might be completely incomprehensible if you are not used to that style of programming.

I am also using a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) instead of all the `join()`'s.  This feature has existed since Java 5.  However, using `Threads` and `CountDownLatches` is kind of old fashioned and you should instead consider using [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)s and such from the `java.util.concurrent` packages.

```
    MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);

    IntStream.range(0, nThreads).forEach(i -> {
        new Thread(() -> {
            int startIndex = i * precision / nThreads + 1;
            int endIndex = (i + 1) * precision / nThreads + 1;
            if (i == nThreads - 1)
                endIndex--;
            Stream<BigDecimal> bigDecims = IntStream.range(startIndex, endIndex)
                .mapToObj(j -> BigDecimal.valueOf(3 * 3 * j * j + 1).divide(factorial(3 * j)));
            BigDecimal total = bigDecims
                 .reduce(BigDecimal.valueOf(0), (x, y) -> x.add(y, mathContext));
            addResult(total);
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }).start();            
    });

    countDownLatch.await();
```